# Magento Subtracting Tax from subtotal instead of adding it

Tags: checkout, paypal, ce-1.9.1.0

For some reason magento is subtracting the tax amount from the subtotal instead of adding it. 5.50 + 6.07 +0.66= 12.23 not 11.57.Grand total is wrong! I looked at my tax settings and they all seem correct so I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks[image]

edit more pictures of config and settings
[image]
The subtotal excluding tax is actually cheaper than the product thats 12.95!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out it was an HHVM issue. HHVM used a different sorting order for prices I guess. Fix was to Set hhvm.enable_zend_sorting = 1 in hhvm/php.ini and then restart HHVM.

Hope this helps anyone with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your shipping could be set to include tax. So, The amount 6.07 could be inclusive of tax.

Comment: No I dont think thats the case just showed the problem without shipping in the image above. Thanks for the help tho :)

Answer (score 0):

You have subtotal and shipping configured to display 'tax-inclusive'

5.50 + 6.07 = 11.57

11.57 - 0.66 = 10.91

The grand total before tax is just showing what the subtotal + shipping would be WITHOUT tax which is already applied.

Check under: System > Configuration > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings

Comment: The actual price of the item is 5.50+ the shipping 6.07+tax 0.66 is 12.23. I have added another picture with out the shipping where its just tax and also showed my configuration settings. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to check the configuration settings in the store scope. Your screenshots are from the default scope.  If you have it configured with 'Excludes Tax' everywhere like that you wouldn't see the results you are seeing.

Comment: I actually solved the problem answer below. Thanks very much for your help it ended up being an HHVM issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to fix it by changing to PHP 5.6 (Single php.ini)
I was having the problem with PHP 7.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 Paypal Invalid Cart Totals Issue including the following errors:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Item total is invalid (#10426: Invalid Data).
>
> PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10426: Invalid Data).

I found the following settings needed to be updated in order to fix:

- Admin > Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings = **Reset all to system defaults**
- Admin > Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > PayPal Express Checkout > Advanced Settings > Transfer Cart Line Items = **No**

In my case I also had the 3rd party extension Shipping Table Rates by Amasty and had to update the following conflicting configuration:

- Admin > Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Shipping Table Rates by Amasty > Use price AFTER discount = **No**
- Admin > Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Shipping Table Rates by Amasty > Use price INCLUDING tax = **No**